# Mixing two different biased coins

Tags: probability, asymptotics

My problem is as follows:

I have two biased coins with probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$ of landing heads. I start with coin 1 and toss it until it lands heads. Then I swap to coin 2 and toss until it lands heads. I then repeat the procedure until I have tossed $n$ times.

$X_n$ is the random variable which counts the number of heads in the process. My objective is to show that with probability $1-e^{-\Omega(n)}$ $X_n$ will be in the interval $[(1-\varepsilon)\mathbb{E}[X_n], (1+\varepsilon)\mathbb{E}[X_n]]$ for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$.

I have observed that if $p_1<p_2$ I know that $np_1\leq\mathbb{E}[X_n]\leq np_2$ so if I can somehow use Chernoff's or Azuma's inequality I don't need to calculate the expectation of $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$. I have tried looking at this problem with Markov chains but I haven't been successful there. I have also observed that for each $n$ I can define new random variables $Y_{k,n}$ where I throw coin 1 $k$ times and coin 2 $n-k$ times and let $Y_{k,n}$ denote the number of heads I got. I then know that for each $n$ there exists a unique $k$ such that $\mathbb{E}[Y_{k,n}]\leq \mathbb{E}[X_n] < \mathbb{E}[Y_{k+1,n}]$. I can't take that approach further though because I can't find suitable bounds for the variance of $X_n$

I'm not asking you to spoil the problem for me. I'm merely asking if someone could push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us go for hints then. A crucial tool is $Y_n$ the number of tosses between the $(n-1)$th head and the $n$th head of coin $2$. Then $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is an i.i.d. sequence and one can easily determine its distribution. For every positive $n$, let  $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k$.

Now, $[X_n\geqslant2k]=[S_k\leqslant n]$ hence, to evaluate $\mathrm P(X_n\geqslant(1+\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n))$, one can choose some $k$ depending on $n$ such that $2k\leqslant (1+\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n)$ and use the upper bound
$$
\mathrm P(X_n\geqslant(1+\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n))\leqslant\mathrm P(S_k\leqslant n).
$$
Likewise, to evaluate $\mathrm P(X_n\leqslant(1-\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n))$, one can choose some $\ell$ depending on $n$ such that $2\ell\geqslant (1-\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n)$ and use the upper bound
$$
\mathrm P(X_n\leqslant(1-\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n))\leqslant\mathrm P(S_\ell\geqslant n).
$$
So one must estimate the probability of these $S_k$ and $S_\ell$ events. This is the realm of [large deviations theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory) but a simple version will be enough for us. Assume for example one wants to bound 
$$
A=\mathrm P(S_k\leqslant n).
$$
Note that for every nonnegative $t$, $[S_k\leqslant n]=[\mathrm e^{-tS_k}\geqslant\mathrm e^{-tn}]$. This remark is at the basis of the so called [Chernoff's bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff%27s_inequality#The_first_step_in_the_proof_of_Chernoff_bounds), in our case,
$$
A=\mathrm P(\mathrm e^{-tS_k}\geqslant\mathrm e^{-tn})\leqslant\mathrm e^{tn}\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{-tS_k})=\mathrm e^{tn}\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{-tY_1})^k.
$$
Assume for a moment that $k=\alpha n+o(n)$ when $n\to\infty$, then $A\leqslant\mathrm e^{-\Omega(n)}$ as soon as there exists a nonnegative $t$ such that
$$
\mathrm e^{t}\,\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{-tY_1})^\alpha \lt1.
$$
When $t\to0$, the LHS of this inequality is $1+t-\alpha t\mathrm E(Y_1)+o(t)$ hence such a parameter $t$ exists as soon as $1-\alpha \mathrm E(Y_1)\lt0$. You know the value of $\mathrm E(Y_1)$ and the only condition on $\alpha $ is 
$$
2\alpha n+o(n)\leqslant (1+\varepsilon)\mathrm E(X_n),
$$
hence the proof that $A\leqslant\mathrm e^{-\Omega(n)}$ is complete if
$$
(1+\varepsilon)\cdot\mathrm E(Y_1)\cdot\xi\gt2\quad
\mbox{with}\quad \xi=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm E(X_n)}{n}.
$$
As you probably already guessed, it happens that
$$
\mathrm E(Y_1)\cdot\xi=2,
$$
hence this strategy succeeds for every positive $\varepsilon$. Likewise for $B=\mathrm P(S_\ell\geqslant n)$.

The relation $\mathrm E(Y_1)\cdot\xi=2$ is standard [renewal theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory), but let me finish by explaining the reason why it holds. In the long run, by the most classical version of the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), it takes about $n=\mathrm E(Y_1)\cdot N$ tosses for $X$ to increase of $2N$ units, that is, $X_n\approx 2N\approx 2n/\mathrm E(Y_1)$. Since $X_n\approx\mathrm E(X_n)$, this yields $\xi=2/\mathrm E(Y_1)$.

Comment: Tell me if some steps are not detailed enough.

Comment: Hello I have similar homework. I dont understand the step when t->0   why the LHS that was previously exponential became of linear form.

Comment: @irrehaare Because $e^t=1+t+o(t)$ when $t\to0$.